# Spell Check not working on HTC M9

Tags: keyboard, htc, htc-one, spell-check

I was wondering is spell check on android the same as the iPhone, that is does the word get underlined, because that doesn't to be happening in my case. I have downloaded Swiftkey and Google Keyboard and both still don't have that option, is there anything I can do? I don't want next word/current word prediction!

Answer (score 0):

It does work, not sure on your device but on the Nexus 6 running 5.1.1 under Settings > Language and Input. There is an option for spell check. I use the Google keyboard and I assure you. It has spell check. It's in the keyboard settings under text correction.

Comment: it seemed to be working for SMS, but not on twitter & other apps :/

Comment: Try this. https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/hangouts/2HZOEgILrsg/0IXxuFAFyY8J I know he is talking about hangouts but maybe it has the same effect on other apps.